set array items into separate variables
I am trying to set each item in an array into their own variables.  Here is what the array looks like:
labels = ["label1", "label2", "label3", "label4", "label5"]

I have already created the variables:
let name1;
let name2;
let name3;
let name4;
let name5;

So I want to set each array item to each variable so that they look like this:
let name1 = "label1";
let name2 = "label2";
let name3 = "label3";
let name4 = "label4";
let name5 = "label5";

I am not really sure with how to proceed with this.

This question is similar to: How do I create dynamic variable names inside a loop?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Note that this isn't normally done. The question is why do you need to create a number of sequential variables called name in the first place? Rather than referring to name1 in your code, you would instead refer to labels[0], instead of name2 you would refer to labels[1] and so on. Introducing a new label ("label6") into your labels array? No problem, just refer to it using labels[5], no need to create a corresponding name variable. Creating sequential variables like this is typically bad practice as that's what you can use arrays for (which is what you have already).

Is this what you want?


           const labels = ["label1", "label2", "label3", "label4", "label5"]

           var name1 = labels[0];
           var name2 = labels[1];
           var name3 = labels[2];
           var name4 = labels[3];
           var name5 = labels[4];

           console.log('name1=' + name1);
           console.log('name5=' + name5);




I do believe this is what I was looking for.  Looks like I was making it more difficult than what it needed to be.  Thank you.

Also, const {name1, name2, name3, name4, name5 } = ["label1", "label2", "label3", "label4", "label5"] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Here is one way to do it:


const labels = ["label1", "label2", "label3", "label4", "label5"];

const [name1, name2, name3, name4, name5] = labels;

console.log('name1=' + name1);
console.log('name5=' + name5);



